# Microsoft Azure Application Service Support for IBM Websphere LIBERTY container?

Tags: java, azure

Does anyone know if IBM Websphere Liberty container is supported on Azure? While I am trying to create a web application and trying to select JAVA Container the options I get is TOMCAT and JETTY only I dont see IBM Websphere Liberty as an available option?

Any help on this? I am trying to migrate some IBM hosted apps to Azure.

UPDATES (04/28) RESOLVED:- We ended up creating a Docker container with Open Liberty and used that as base docker image for Azure web-apps. We did face some issues and that were fixed wrt DOCKER File and SSL for azure-websites as our web-app was talking with another Azure Web-API over ssl (HTTPS) so gotta take care of it. that thread is here on how to copy the .CER file as JSK to Docker Image. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/98429780?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official document,only tomcat and jetty are supported in the Container Options.

[image]

Azure Web APP service is PASS level service. In my opinion, such heavy enterprise-level intermediate container like `WebLogic` or `Websphere` are obviously not suitable for PASS level service,even though for the Docker.If you want to migrate IBM hosted apps to Azure,i suggest you considering to use [Azure VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) to host enterprise application.

Comment: Thanks, we will try and avoid the IAAS way and would rather look going PAAS. I have manage to create a Docker Image (OPEN Liberty) and I have created an Azure Web-app using this docker image. The webapp renders good as its clean slate. I would like to know how I can deploy a WAR file to this app service (which uses OPEN Liberty) I tried the bash and war deploy as mentioned in microsoft docs but that doesnt help. Now its all about getting the WAR file deployed there in the correct directory.

Comment: Just to seal this up:- I RESOLVED it. I created a DOCKER image with Open Liberty and used that as a docker image for Azure Web-Apps. We have to ensure *.azurewebsites.net SSL Certificate is copied to the keys.jks store in open liberty whcih can be done with DOCKERFILE which is used to build the docker image. I had another thread for it, it may help:- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/98429780?noredirect=1